# Can a SAS DS2 data step create a view?

Tags: sas-ds2

```
Proc DS2;
data Iris_v / view= Iris_v;
    method run();
        set Iris;
    end;
run; quit;
```

results in

```
ERROR: Compilation error.
ERROR: BASE driver, unknown option
ERROR: BASE driver, Table IRIS_V does not exist or cannot be accessed or created
ERROR: Unable to execute CREATE TABLE statement for table work.Iris_v.
NOTE: PROC DS2 has set option NOEXEC and will continue to prepare statement
```

However, intellisense in Enterprise Guide suggests `view=` as an option after `/`. 
Do I make an error or is intellisense wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The editor just cannot tell the difference between a DS2 DATA statement and a BASE SAS DATA statement.  It is just an editor after all and not an actual compiler.